# Error Object is null stack trace not show the line

Tags: c#, exception, log4net

I try catch use Exception to get stack trace. Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", but when I log file use log4net, I log ex.StackTrace as well, it doesn't show the line of exception.

Do you know why? Regular, it's always show but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the pdb files if you want to view the lines. Also just doing ToString on the exception should give you the stacktrace.

Comment: You mean if I release just dlls, it will doesn't show stack trace?

Comment: No, it wont, DLL files contain just MSIL, which has no reference to what line the current executing code belongs to. PDB files contain debugging information to map MSIL to source code.